# get_user_meta returning empty when it's NOT empty

Tags: user-meta

I am writing a filter. Here is the scenario... it's for a website selling yoga retreats. I have successfully created a new meta profile field called "retreat_contracts" which is meant to store the liability waivers a given user has completed.

There's only one piece that's not working. For some reason, get_user_meta is not returning a value. I have double and triple-checked the meta field key, and it is 'retreat_contracts' without a doubt. I can also verify that 'retreat_contracts' is NOT empty in my profile or database (it's currently mostly curse words), so $current_contracts should have that value, right?

```
$current_contracts =  get_user_meta( $user_id, 'retreat_contracts', TRUE);
if (empty($current_contracts)) {
    // DO THIS STUFF
} else {
    // DO THIS STUFF
}
```

It should be operating the "else" stuff, but it's not.

Any insight? I am sure there's something obvious I'm missing, but I've been looking at it for two days, and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Firstly, try if (!$current_contracts)... Secondly, are you storing a string or array there? Please echo/var_dump() it in both scenarios to check the problem. This is the best way to find out what the problem is, like a misspell...

Comment: Thanks for responding. Part of the code I didn't include (for purposes of streamlining my question) was assigning the value of $current_contracts to my user field 'retreat_contracts'. I did echo the value of $current_contracts, and it shows up as empty/blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confidently say that it ***is empty*** at the point at which your code checks the variable. The three possibilities are:

1. `$user_id` is not set or is set to an incorrect value. As you don't
   show the code that sets this value, I can't tell.
2. You are using the wrong key.
3. [Something is hooked into `get_user_metadata`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L480) and is causing a
   problem.

While I am not 100% sure, I am fairly sure that those are an exclusive list.

If you can post your code with more context I might be able to do better.

Comment: OHMIGOSH. THANK YOU! I am such a doofus. I'd been looking at this for days, and I'd just failed to set $user_id. HA! I knew it was something like that. I need to get these glasses checked.